# Перезагрузка функции кнопкой

Tags: javascript, button, reload

Есть кнопка СТАРТ!, на кнопку нажимаешь, и после определенного интервала (10 секунд к примеру) нужно сделать так, чтобы эта кнопка уже имела совершенно другой смысл - ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗКА.

т.е. мне нужно осуществить перезагрузку функции с помощью кнопки, и нужно чтобы это работало бесконечно -
старт -> перезагрузка -> старт -> перезагрузка -> старт....

можно конечно просто перезагружать страницу, но это не вариант.

Comment: я так понимаю что нужно делать замыканием.. но не могу себе представить вообще

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под перезагрузкой? Функция должна выполнять другие действия или сброс значений переменных?

Comment: к изначальным параметрам возвратиться, сброс, да

Comment: Насколько я понимаю нужно что-то вроде: const starting_param_1 = 'some_value';
const starting_param_2 = 'another_value';

button.onclick = function(e){ 
  let local_param_1 = starting_param_1;
  let local_param_2 = starting_param_2;
  setTimeout(function(){
    local_param_1 = starting_param_1;
    local_param_2 = starting_param_2;
  }, 10 * 1000);
}

Comment: т.е. мы просто конечные результаты параметров всей функции приравниваем к изначальным?? а если функция гигантская? циклом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/* create_context возращает функцию, которая будет возвращать вашу функцию
 с аргументами, которые вы передадите в create_context */
function create_context(fn, ...params){
  return function(){
    return function(){
      return fn(...params)
    }
  }
}
async function func_to_exec(param_1, param_2, ...params){
  console.log(param_1, param_2, ...params)
  // Функция изменяет свои параметры
  param_1 = param_1 + 'data'
  param_2 = param_1 + ''
  // И продолжает выполнятся
}

let context = create_context(func_to_exec, 'par1', 'par2', 'par3')
let button_handler = context();
let button = document.getElementById('but')
button.onclick = function(e){
  button_handler()
  // Через секунду после нажатия кнопки функция, что выполняется "обнулится", но параметры с которыми она создавалась "запомнены"
  setTimeout(function(){
    button_handler = context();
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<button id="but">Кнопка</button>
```